# Vue2 - How to get a reference to a method of the component inside the data-section of a Composition-Api-Based Component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm migrating a TypeScript "Class-Based Vue Component" to "Composition-Api-Based Component" in a Vuejs2 project.

In the component I use inside the "data" section a reference to a method of the same component.

in the class-based component it looks liks this (which works fine):

```html
<template>
    <section class="my-dynamic-form">
        <!-- render the form -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <div v-for="formRow in formRows">
            <!-- ... -->
            <button
                v-if=" formRow.type === 'ACTION_BUTTON'"
                @click="formRow.action">
                {{ formRow.text }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>


<script lang="ts">

import Vue from "vue";

export default class MyFormComponent extends Vue {

    public formRows: Array<any> = [
        // ...
        {
            type: "ACTION_BUTTON",
            text: 'Save',
            action: this.update, // <--- works
        }
    ];

    update() {
        alert("update data on server...");
    }
}

</script>
```

After changing it to a "Composition-Api-Based Component" I have the problem that the reference to method "update" is not recognized anymore .. giving the error "TS2339: Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Vue'". Here is the code:

```html
<template>
    <section class="my-dynamic-form">
        <!-- render the form -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <div v-for="formRow in formRows">
            <!-- ... -->
            <button
                v-if=" formRow.type === 'ACTION_BUTTON'"
                @click="formRow.action">
                {{ formRow.text }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>


<script lang="ts">

import {defineComponent} from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            // ...
            formRows: [
                // ...
                {
                    type: "ACTION_BUTTON",
                    text: 'Save',
                    action: this.update, // <--- error - TS2339: Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Vue'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update() {
            alert("update data on server...");
        },
    },
});

</script>
```

My Question is: how do I get a reference to a method of the component inside the data-section of the Composition-Api-Based Component?

Comment: You are not using the Composition API, but regular Vue syntax. In this case, you might want to define the data in a computed property. You could also go for the Composition API and define everything within the setup() function.

Comment: thank you. using a computed property solved my problem.